# Plotting 3d connections in Java or C++

Tags: java, c++, 3d, visualization

I'm developing a visualization software and my current aim is to visualize some sort of networks in 3d. It doesn't really matter how the nodes and edges are represented, as long as one can see the network in 3d. I'm a newcomer in the field of 3d objects, so any libraries, tutorials or websites are welcome.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a way to display these, you may want to try an existing visualization program like [ParaView](http://paraview.org).  It is built on an extensive visualization library called [VTK](http://vtk.org).  Both are open source and cross platform.  VTK can be programmed using Java, C++, and other languages.

Comment: thanks, this might actually work.